# Can I post an ePub book on my website host and then hide a link in a page so only those I want can read the book? Is there HTML code for that?

Tags: epub, website

I have written a small booklet.  It will be used in an upcoming event, and I want the leaders to get an advanced epub copy.  I would like to attach this to my organizations html website.  It would be great if they could see the book, but I want them to be able to download it at a minimum.  I have searched many times for the HTML codes to do this and nothing I have found works.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The following methods can be still reached if your clients are given the webpage link by you. The first several methods take you to a webpage where you need to place the epub link.

1. Wrap link with an HTML comment tag: `<!--<a href="https://www.ese.net/epub.html></a>-->`
2. Or use CSS and put a  `class="hidden"` in the link and use the CSS style code below. Or use `'display:none'` as another option.
3. Or style the actual link inline directly:  `style="visibility:hidden;"`

***Alternative:***
If you want the epub to immediately start downloading at moment of click, replace the html page link with your actual epub link like this:

```
<a href="your-epub.epub" class="hidden">EPUB</a>
```

CSS styling for the above:

```
<style>
/* keep the space it consumes but make it invisible */
.hidden {visibility: hidden;}
/* remove the space and make it invisible */
.none {display: none;}
</style>
```

See **MDN Mozilla** website (or w3schools) for display visibility, display hidden, display none.
Welcome to ESE.